# Prove/disprove: In a graph with at least one component that does not contain a hamilton circuit, we can make it hamiltorian by adding a vertex

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove/disprove: In a graph $G$ with at least one component that does not contain a Hamiltonian circuit, we can add a vertex $x$ and certain edges that connect it with certain vertices in the graph, such that we get a graph where every component of the graph has a Hamiltonian circuit.

My answer was:

> Disprove. Take for example the claw graph with 3 vertices. Any addition of $x$ and certain edges will not make a Hamiltonian circuit. (it does make a Hamiltonian path, but not a circuit.)

Is that correct or am I missing something?

Comment: If by "claw graph with 3 vertices" you mean K(1,2), then you can indeed make a Hamiltonian cycle. Are you thinking Eulerian cycle maybe?

Comment: Yes I mean $K(1,3)$. How can I make a Hamiltonian cycle in $K(1,3)$?

Comment: Oops, hit the wrong key, sorry; I meant K(1,2). My mistake. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "claw graph with 3 vertices".  If you mean $P_3$ or $K_{1,2}$, then indeed we can make a Hamiltonian circuit, by creating a square.  If you mean $K_{1,3}$, then your example is correct but your proof is incomplete.  It can only help (in terms of producing a Hamiltonian circuit) to connect $x$ to every vertex in  $K_{1,3}$.  Consider the three vertices of degree 2 that result.  Each path from one to another must pass through either $x$ or the other vertex of degree 4.  But in a Hamiltonian circuit one needs to be able to get from each to the next (three paths) that do not intersect.  Contradiction.

Specific errors/omissions in OP's solution:

1. Does not discuss which edges are added to $x$, except for the general and unsupported claim "any".
2. Does not justify why such an addition will not make a Hamiltonian circuit, or why it will make a Hamiltonian path.
3. Uses the nonstandard term "claw graph with 3 vertices" for $K_{1,3}$ (which has 4 vertices).

Comment: Yes I meant $K_{1,3}$.

Comment: So my answer is correct?

Comment: @TheNotMe It is incomplete...

Comment: Incomplete as in sense of a full mathematical proof?

Comment: Easier argument: I am going to denote by $u_1$ respectively $v_1,v_2,v_3$ the vertices of $K_{13}$, Assume there is a Hamiltonian cycle. Then the cycle has $5$ vertices, thus two of the $v_i$'s must be adjacent...

Comment: @TheNotMe yes. More exactly, you need to explain WHY this is true:" Any addition of $x$  and certain edges will not make a Hamiltonian circuit. "

Comment: Thank you so much. At least, I am glad that I could supply a disproving graph. I have an exam in combinatorics soon and having trouble with solving Graph questions.
Thanks alot for your helpful answer!

Comment: @N.S. what are $v_1, v_2, v_3$? the vertices on the right part of $K_{1,3}$?

Comment: @TheNotMe Yup. $u_1$ on one side and $v_1,v_2,v_3$ on the other...

Comment: But you haven't mentioned adding another vertex, or setting new edges from that. Frankly, your argument is unclear for me.

Comment: Nevermind, I understood! Thank you!